# read_excel function changes some characters to unicode ones since pandas package upgrade

Tags: python, pandas, unidecoder

I have upgraded pandas package, new version is : 1.4.2 and xlrd package, new version is 2.0.1

Now, when I read python file with the following command :

**import pandas as pd
pd.read_excel('myfile.xlsx')**

I got the following warning:
*UserWarning: Workbook contains no default style, apply openpyxl's default*

And my result is :

| foo | bar |
| --- | --- |
| _x0031_01259 | COMMUNAUTE_x0020_DE_x0020_COMMUNES_x0020_FIER_x0020_ET_x0020_USSES |

While it should be :

| foo | bar |
| --- | --- |
| 101259 | COMMUNAUTE DE COMMUNES FIER ET USSES |

So in some columns, 1 is replaced by *x0031*, 2 is replaced by *x0033*, space is replaced by *x0020*, etc.

I tried to add engine parameter set to openpyxl but same warning message and same dataframe result.

Before Pandas package upgrade, I already had the problem but with engine parameter set to xlrd, it was working (but I had a warning saying that newest version won't support xlrd)

Any idea how to read correctly the file?

Answer (score 1):

`xlrd` package is not used for `.xlsx` files in `pandas`.

As you can read in [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html), for `.xlsx` it is using `openpyxl` that does not handle reading `xlsx` properly in some specific scenarios, causing error you have described - [check this bug report](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/1410)

It has been working for you before, because `xlrd` used to support `.xlsx` files, but [since version 2.0.0](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rst#200-11-december-2020) it supports only "classic" `.xls` files.

As a workaround, you can use `xlrd` [code snippet from 1.x.x version](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/blob/bbccdcb96e40b590d71ed14682237bea1e8f1dc5/xlrd/xlsx.py#L136) in pandas, however you have to ensure your columns does not include strings like `_x0000_` that you want to preserve:

```
def unescape(s,
             subber=re.compile(r"_x[0-9A-Fa-f]{4,4}_", re.UNICODE).sub,
             repl=lambda mobj: chr(int(mobj.group(0)[2:6], 16))):
    if "_" in s:
        return subber(repl, s)

    return s

df["column"] = df["column"].apply(unescape)
```